# Excel: return cell value from a specific cell

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

I need to take the cell value, which cell row position is variable by another cell value.

Ex:

B2 = 10

I need to take the value of M10

If it was B2=6 I would have needed the value of M6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching for "INDIRECT"
in your example :

```
B2 = INDIRECT("M" & 10, TRUE) ' Will return the value of M10.
```

True is for "A1" ref, FALSE for "L1C1"

Let's say, the line you are aiming is indicated in A4

if A4 = 6

```
B2 = INDIRECT("M" & A4, TRUE) ' Will return the value of M6.
```

Comment: This is it!.... Ref.: Openoffice [INDIRECT function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_INDIRECT_function) _(btw: second parameter, *notation* is `true` by default)_

Comment: @user171102: Please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim NewValue as string
NewValue = range("B2").value
Range("M & NewValue")
```

This would give you m + whatever is is B2 cell

Sorry This is VBA is you know that.